# Radio button is not working properly

Tags: html, radio-button

In my web page I have placed some radio buttons. But these buttons are not working properly. I can check multiple buttons.

code:

```
<label for="abc" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">xyz</label>
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="abc" >        
<label for="bcd" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">abc</label>
<input type="radio" id="bcd" name="bcd" >
<label for="efg" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">ccc</label>
<input type="radio" id="efg" name="efg" >
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6aCR/)

I want to check only one button. Please any one help me.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Because you've different value for `name` attribute, they should have a common `name` value, just like you group items.. for example

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" />

<!-- You can select any one from each group -->

<input type="radio" name="group2" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmsh2/)

Comment: Ah man, this saved me some serious frustration. Some times it's good to go back to the fundamentals! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
<label for="abc" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">xyz</label>
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="abc" >        
<label for="bcd" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">abc</label>
<input type="radio" id="bcd" name="abc" >
<label for="efg" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">ccc</label>
<input type="radio" id="efg" name="abc" >
```

All inputs must have the same name="" attribute value

Answer (score 4):

Radio buttons which are grouped together must have the same case-sensitive `name` property.

```
<label for="input1">First Input</label>
<input type="radio" id="input1" name="inputGroup" >
<label for="input2">Second Input</label>
<input type="radio" id="input2" name="inputGroup" >
<label for="input3">Third Input</label>
<input type="radio" id="input3" name="inputGroup" >
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6aCR/2/).

From the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio):

> Radio buttons are like checkboxes except that when several share the same control `name`, they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I reached this thread searching the keywords "html radio not working". After reviewing my code, I noticed that I used a javascript method "event.preventDefault();" in this  custom function that I've made where the HTML node that triggered this event in that custom function were the "not working" radio  parent. So I solved my problem removing the "event.preventDefault();". If someone reached this thread in the future, I hope this help you somehow (even for debbuging purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Give same name to all radio button from which you want to select one option

```
<label for="abc" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">xyz</label>
<input type="radio" id="abc" name="abc" >        
<label for="bcd" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">abc</label>
<input type="radio" id="bcd" name="abc" >
<label for="efg" style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:40px">ccc</label>
<input type="radio" id="efg" name="abc" >
```

Now it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

Name attribute needs to be the same. Name groups radio buttons together to make them one unit.

Answer (score 0):

Name them the same way, and in your php or receiving code it will be something like

```
$_POST['name'] = 'value of selected radio button'
```

Answer (score 0):

The name setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.
If you couldn't define which group the current button belongs to, you could only have one group of radio buttons on each page.
**e.g :**

```
<input type="radio" name="fruit1" value="Apple"> Apple <br>
<input type="radio" name="fruit1" value="Apricot" checked> Apricot <br>
<input type="radio" name="fruit1" value="Avocado"> Avocado
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="fruit2" value="Banana"> Banana<br>
<input type="radio" name="fruit2" value="Breadfruit"> Breadfruit<br>
<input type="radio" name="fruit2" value="Bilberry" checked>  Bilberry
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the name the same attribute.
The checked attribute can be used to indicate which value should be selected. Somewhere in your syntax for the value you want checked write checked="checked"