# HTML radio button not working according to definition?

Tags: html

From Wikipedia:

*"A radio button or option button is a type of graphical user interface element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options."*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button

Since that's what I want on my page, I used an input button of type radio:

```
    <form id="run_units">
        <input type="radio" value="1">Miles 
        <input type="radio" value="2">Kilometers
    </form>
```

And yet, when I test my page, it's allowing me to select both Miles and Kilometers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Best to use something more like the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio) or [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) as a technical reference.

Comment: @ajp15243 Hmm... the given example at the linked page seems to fall to the same trap as OP...

Comment: @Teemu Interesting, it does... I'm surprised that it doesn't mention sharing a common name seeing as limiting the number of selections is the primary difference between radio buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: @Teemu Hah, it sure does. Good job, W3C wiki. Fortunately, MDN explicitly mentions the need for the same `name` value in its description of radio inputs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button is not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710804/radio-button-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give to each input a name. The names should be equal.

```
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="1">Miles 
    <input type="radio" name="distance" value="2">Kilometers
```

Why to use the *name* attribute? Because the checkbox is used in forms, and each `<input>` should have a name, by which is sent to the server.

Answer (score 3):

In order for the choice to limited to just one radio button you need to give both buttons the same `name` for example:

```
<form id="run_units">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="distance">Miles 
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="distance">Kilometers
</form>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pQMG/

All the radio buttons that you want limited to a "group" should have the same `name`