# HTML 5 , Radio Button property not working properly

Tags: html

As we know that, Radio button function in HTML allows user to Select one of options on page. But when I used "radio" . I am able to select all of options on a page! Please help me with it! Here's example of those types of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <title> Survey </title> </head>
<body LEFTMARGIN="500" TOPMARGIN = "200"><font face = "BROADWAY">
<input type="radio" name="m"/>MS Dhoni <br />
<input type="radio" name="v" />Virat Kohli<br />
<input type="radio" name="s"/> Sachin Tendulkar <br/></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use name attibute with single common name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710804/radio-button-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 3):

Radio buttons allow you to select one item from a radio *group*. This isn't the same as *on the page* because you can have multiple radio groups in a single form.

The `name` attribute is used to distinguish between groups.

All your radio buttons have **different** `names` so they are members of different groups.

Give them all the same `name` and use the `value` attribute to distinguish between them.

Add `<label>` elements to associate the text that describes the radio button with the correct button.

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="something" value="m"> MS Dhoni</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="something" value="v"> Virat Kohli</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="something" value="s"> Sachin Tendulkar</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give them the same name but a different value.

Like this:

```html
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female <br />

<hr>

<p>In your case:</p>

<input type="radio" name="person" value="m"/>MS Dhoni <br />
<input type="radio" name="person" value="v"/>Virat Kohli<br />
<input type="radio" name="person" value="s"/>Sachin Tendulkar <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This is how we have to use radio button.

```html
<input type="radio" name="player"/>MS Dhoni <br />
<input type="radio" name="player" />Virat Kohli<br />
<input type="radio" name="player"/> Sachin Tendulkar <br/>
```