# Radio buttons clear in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 radio buttons,

> radio1: Male, radio2: Female

When we click on `male` button, one text box appears and we can write name in it,and also when we click on `female` new text box appear and we can write name.

But my issue is when I click on `male` or `female` buttons, its value does not clear automatically.

How to clear values on click of radio buttons, so that everytime radio is pressed empty text box appears.

Comment: Share some code (what have you tried so far) in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710804/radio-button-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: its not duplicate, jst read what i am trying to tell

Comment: @tom Showing us the current code is pretty much a bare minimum requirement for SO questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand the problem, think this is your answer

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='clearValue()'>
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
```

and then, in a controller:

```
$scope.clearValue = function() {
     $scope.name = '';
}
```

Comment: yes quiet similar,

two radio buttons, one text box, bt ciking on any radio button, value of text box gonna clear

Comment: What is the difference? why 'quiet'??@tom