# Is it possible to avoid multi clicking in a form in php?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I created a database with two tables inside where I get questions from and insert answers in it. Now I made the answer to be inserted using only radio buttons like in this index.php page

```
<?php 
    include "conn.php";

    $query="SELECT*FROM questions";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
<form action="select.php" method="POST">
    <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){;?>
    <p><?php echo $row['question'];?></p>

    <input type="radio" name="answ1" value="<?php echo $row['answ1'];?>"><?php echo $row['answ1'];?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="answ2" value="<?php echo $row['answ2'];?>"><?php echo $row['answ2'];?><br><br>

<?php };?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now for each question I query two input fields which contains two answers. But the problem is that the same question about radio buttons can be clicked.

How can I avoid this problem and is there a more suitable way to use such forms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710804/radio-button-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons must have the same name regardless of their values

Change the name of your radio buttons to answ then check if $_POST['answ']=={the value of $row['answ1'] or $row['answ2']} in order to know which answer was selected