# Radio buttons in HTML form not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I'm learning Javascript and forms in HTML and I knew about radio buttons. But the problem is when I'm coding 3 radio buttons for testing, somehow it doesn't work, and when I check "1" (it's a name) and I choose another one like "2", it doesn't uncheck "1"! Does my browser have a problem, or my code is wrong? I'm using the Microsoft Edge browser, and this is my code:

```html
<form>
  <label for="html">This one is Html </label>
  <input type="radio" name="html" id="html" value="HTML">
  <br>
  <label for="css">This one is Css</label>
  <input type="radio" name="css" id="css" value="CSS">
  <br>
  <label for="javscript">This one is Javascript</label>
  <input type="radio" name="javscript" id="javascript" value="JAVASCRIPT">
</form>
```

Anyone know what is my problem?

Comment: you need to keep same `name` in order to group them

Comment: the name should be same. refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp for more information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radio button is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710804/radio-button-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

`name` property is as a group. so if you set the same `name` on radio buttons, they are being in same group.

```html
<form>
  <label for="html">This one is Html </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="html" value="HTML">
  <br>
  <label for="css">This one is Css</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="css" value="CSS">
  <br>
  <label for="javscript">This one is Javascript</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="javascript" value="JAVASCRIPT">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you just need to use the same `name` for each group, here i used `codetype`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="html">This one is Html </label>
        <input type="radio" name="codetype" id="html" value="HTML">
        <br>
        <label for="css">This one is Css</label>
        <input type="radio" name="codetype" id="css" value="CSS">
        <br>
        <label for="javscript">This one is Javascript</label>
        <input type="radio" name="codetype" id="javascript" value="JAVASCRIPT">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please you can use radio button that time all radio button `name` set same then you select at that time one radio button.

```html
  <form>
      <label for="html">This one is Html </label>
      <input type="radio" name="skill" id="html" value="HTML">
      <br>
      <label for="css">This one is Css</label>
      <input type="radio" name="skill" id="css" value="CSS">
      <br>
      <label for="javscript">This one is Javascript</label>
      <input type="radio" name="skill" id="javascript" value="JAVASCRIPT">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use the same name attribute value for each group.**

```html
<form>
  <label for="html">This one is Html </label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_button" id="html" value="HTML">
  <br>
  <label for="css">This one is Css</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_button" id="css" value="CSS">
  <br>
  <label for="javscript">This one is Javascript</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_button" id="javascript" value="JAVASCRIPT">
</form>
```